# Quality qualifies quality

Tags: adjectives, qualifiers

I don’t understand how a quality qualifies the same quality (even though my native language does).

For example, *small size*, *yellow color*, *hot weather*.

I think *size is small*, *color is yellow* and *weather is hot* seems strange to me.

Could you let me understand how they works?

Comment: Sometimes the "size" of something is "small", other times it's "big". And the "colour" of something might be "yellow" or, say, "blue" or "green". In English I can say *My shirt is yellow* or *This is my yellow shirt* without including the word "colour" at all. But I can also say *My shirt is coloured yellow, The colour of my shirt is yellow,...* What exactly is it you don't understand here?

Comment: What I don’t understand is how quality qualifies quality... doesn’t quality belong to concrete nouns like a thing or a person?

Comment: If someone is obnoxious, how can you say that they are *mildly obnoxious*, unless you have a word that can modify this attribute of a person? *Mildly* isn't some independent quality -- it **modifies** *obnoxious*.

Comment: Thank you by the way I’m not obnoxious...

Comment: LOL. True, you are not obnoxious. I was just creating examples. :)

Comment: It's a trivial issue of terminology, but some people would say an adjective is only an adjective when it modifies a ***noun***. If it's being used to modify another ***adjective***, they'll start calling it an ***adverb***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two mean slightly different things.

> Size is small

means we are talking about the size that is labelled small. If you ask for a T-shirt in "size small" you want one whose size is "Small".

> A small size

means any of the sizes at the smaller end of the range.

If you ask for a T-shirt in "a small size" you might mean "Small", "Extra-small" or "Extra-extra-small". Or even medium if the manufacturer is known for producing T-shirts smaller than others.

Similarly "the colour yellow" means exactly that colour, whereas "a yellow colour" might mean amber, saffron, jonquil, or a yellowish brown.